# Why is state undefined when passed through React Router Link Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass props through the React Router Link Component but the state remains undefined, does anyone have an idea of why?

The Route:

```
<Route path="/movie" component={Movie} render={props => 
<Movie {...props} />} />
```

The Link:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/movie', state: { fromMovieList: true}}} > 
Title </Link>
```

The component rendered from the path "/movie"

```
class Movie extends React.Component {

  render () {
    console.log(this.props.location.state); // undefined
    return (
      <div> Hello </div>
        )
      }
    }

export default Movie;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must wrap the **Movie** component with [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter);

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest Route's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
export default withRouter(Movie);
```

Comment: got it working in a functional component by using the react-router useLocation hook inside the child/linked component. https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation

Comment: yes without using withRouter hook but only need is useLocation hook it works. I faced the same problem.